# Replace two or more spaces with Regex in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I am horrible with Regex stuff. I would like to use a regular expression in C# to turn any two or more spaces into non-breaking spaces. I would like to leave single spaces alone.

```
Sample     Sample
```

Would produce

```
Sample&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sample
```

But

```
Sample Sample
```

Wouldn't be affected.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) as the replacement argument. In C# 3.0 or newer you can use a lambda function:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, " {2,}", x => x.Value.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it would be simple. I just have a hard time with that stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It's based on zero-width positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.TEXT.REGULAREXPRESSIONS.REGEX.%23CTOR%22%29;k%28REGEX%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true#grouping_constructs)

```
var rx = new Regex(" (?= )|(?<= ) ");

var str = "ab   cde f";
var res = rx.Replace(str, "&nbsp;");

// res == ab&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cde f
```

Comment: @Mark Instead I wanted to it in the "simple" way but I forgot the use MatchEvaluator function :-)